# API for simple File (line count) functions in Java

Tags: java, apache, large-files, line-count

Hi : Given an arbitrary file (java), I want to count the lines.

This is easy enough, for example, using Apache's FileUtils.readLines(...) method...

However, for large files, reading a whole file in place is ludicrous (i.e. just to count lines).

One home-grown option : Create BufferedReader or use the FileUtils.lineIterator function, and count the lines.

However, *I'm assuming there could be a (low memory), up to date API for doing simple large File operations with a minimal amount of boiler plate for java --- Does any such library or functionality exist anywhere in the any of the Google, Apache, etc... open-source Java utility libraries ?*

Comment: What's wrong with the `BufferedReader`?

Comment: you can get size, isnt that better than line numbers?

Comment: You can't count lines without reading them. See also LineNumberReader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 8 short way:

```
 Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).count();
```

But most memory effiecint:

```
try(InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(name))){
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096 * 16];
    int c;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while ((c = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
       for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
           if (buf[i] == '\n') lineCount++;
       }
    }
}
```

You do not need String objects in this task at all.

Comment: One problem with the second approach is that it counts the line separator characters so if you have a file with one million lines it will return 999999.

Answer (score 6):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
int nLines = Files.readLines(file, charset, new LineProcessor<Integer>() {
  int count = 0;
  Integer getResult() {
    return count;
  }
  boolean processLine(String line) {
    count++;
    return true;
  }
});
```

which won't hold the whole file in memory or anything.

Comment: Yup : Guava is certainly the next best thing - but I'm looking for a one line solution.

Comment: Counting lines in a file probably isn't a common enough use case to get its own support from Guava, I'm afraid -- not when we can support more general things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Without a library:

```
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    try {
        while (br.readLine() != null) count++;
    } finally { 
        br.close(); 
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that makes use of Apache Commons IO library. You can pass `null` for `encoding` to pick the platform default.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;

public static long countLines(String filePath, String encoding)
throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    LineIterator lineIterator = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, encoding);
    long lines = 0;
    try {
        while ( lineIterator.hasNext() ) {
            lines++;
            lineIterator.nextLine();
        }
    } finally {
        LineIterator.closeQuietly( lineIterator );
    }
    return lines;
}
```