# Populating ArrayList from file without including formatting info and back-slashes

Tags: java, arraylist

To start, no this is not a homework assignment.  I am fresh out of highschool and am trying to do some personal projects before college. I've been trying to populate an ArrayList with elements from a document. The document looks like:

item1

item2

item3

...

itemN

After failing many times on my own, I tried different solutions from this website. Most recently, this one got me the closest to what I desire:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/MyName/Desktop/names.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            names.add(line);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
    //String[] array = (String[]) names.toArray(); Not necessary that it is in an array
}
```

The only problem is that this returns something rather ugly in the console:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1347\cocoasubrtf570
{\fonttbl\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times-Roman;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx577\tx1155\tx1733\tx2311\tx2889\tx3467\tx4045\tx4623\tx5201\tx5779\tx6357\tx6935\tx7513\tx8091\tx8669\tx9247\tx9825\tx10403\tx10981\tx11559\tx12137\tx12715\tx13293\tx13871\tx14449\tx15027\tx15605\tx16183\tx16761\tx17339\tx17917\tx18495\tx19072\tx19650\tx20228\tx20806\tx21384\tx21962\tx22540\tx23118\tx23696\tx24274\tx24852\tx25430\tx26008\tx26586\tx27164\tx27742\tx28320\tx28898\tx29476\tx30054\tx30632\tx31210\tx31788\tx32366\tx32944\tx33522\tx34100\tx34678\tx35256\tx35834\tx36412\tx36990\tx37567\tx38145\tx38723\tx39301\tx39879\tx40457\tx41035\tx41613\tx42191\tx42769\tx43347\tx43925\tx44503\tx45081\tx45659\tx46237\tx46815\tx47393\tx47971\tx48549\tx49127\tx49705\tx50283\tx50861\tx51439\tx52017\tx52595\tx53173\tx53751\tx54329\tx54907\tx55485\tx56062\tx56640\tx57218\tx57796\li577\fi-578

\f0\fs24 \cf0 \CocoaLigature0 item1\
item2\
item3\
...
itemN\
}
```

How can i get it to read from the file but not include all of the back-slashes and formatting info?

Comment: If you're not just trying to learn the java's old IO routines use a library such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691420/api-for-simple-file-line-count-functions-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to really save the file as text file. Your file looks like an RTF file at the moment. Open Pages application and open that file. Go to File... Export to... Plain Text... and save it into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `names.txt` file got saved as RTF (Rich Text Format).  Make sure you convert it to plain text.